# Choosing game image assets (sprites/textures) for AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

Which is the 'best practice' on using image resources for developing Android games using AndEngine ?
The 'best' way, means loading images/sprites/textures effectively, high performance, won't use up too many device resources (GPU, memory, etc.)

Assume that this game has several characters and maps. Each different character has many animations, and each different map has different tile sets.

**Question 1: Sprite files**
a. *One (large/gigantic) sprite sheet.* Contains all possible sprites of all characters and maps in a single file.
b. *Lots of single sprite files*. One file contains one sprite. For example, total sprites will be more than 100 files.
c. *Combined: more than one sprite sheet*. One sprite sheet for one type of character / map tiles. For example, character A will have "char_A_spritesheet.png", map X will have "map_X_spritesheet.png".
Which is the best option ?

**Question 2: Image file type**
Should it .jpg, .png, or something else ?

Comment: I'm just asking because I'm curious, are you SURE you want to use AndEngine and not LibGDX? LibGDX is simpler and more efficient, as far as I know - and cross-platform too.

Comment: the project is already started using AndEngine, but not much, maybe still 15%. It has a short deadline too (about 1 and half month). If you can assure me that using libGDX could help make the development quicker and improve the game's quality, I will definitely use libGDX from now.

Comment: It kinda depends on the game, albeit I'm fairly certain that a 2D game would be much much faster in LibGDX, especially because it even has proper documentation unlike what AndEngine provides (does it even HAVE a documentation?)

There is a wiki, and there are multiple game examples, if you somewhat can lay out how much of the Game is already done in AndEngine and how dependent it is on AndEngine, I'll be able to judge whether switching is better.

Check it out: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki

I know basics,albeit I kinda avoided the texture packing and animations. It does not seem hard.

Comment: You convinced me, I'll try libGDX soon, thank you. :)

Comment: You are welcome :D I think it will help greatly. AndEngine seems to have too many unspecified stuff going on, that tinkering and hacking it together to work is definitely a hindrance with a close deadline. There are many good tutorials out too for LibGDX, and I even did desktop/android cross-platform networking in it with Kryonet. Really cool and easy.